# Usage of boolean variable without comparison in while loop

Tags: java, flags

```
boolean flag=true;
while(flag)
{
   //code(flag=false;)
}
```

In the above code ,inside the while loop condition simply `flag` is given. How does the while condition satisfy here?

Comment: Here flag is assigned true ,inside the while loop simply flag is given my qstn is how does the while condition satisfies here?

Comment: While wants a boolean expression. `flag` is a simple expression that evaluates to whatever value currently is in `flag` variable.

Comment: `while(flag)` is the shortened notation for `while(flag == true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional expression needs to be a `boolean`. This could include using a constant (`true`), equality (`==`), inequality (`!=`, `>`, `<`), or method call (`.equals()`).

You already have a `boolean` variable, and this is a constant (not in the term that its value/reference cannot change), and therefore a valid conditional expression.

The while loop will run as long as the expression evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the syntax of the while loop.  It has a condition and a body.  It repeats as long as the condition is true.  The body of the loop performs the work and update the condition if it needs to terminate the loop.

```
while(<condition>){
  <body>
}
```

Here's an example:

Repeat until i reaches the value 10.

```
boolean reachTen = false;
int i=0;
while(! reachTen ){
  System.out.println(i++);
  if (i == 10) reachTen = true;        
}
```

I often do not use a fag.  Instead, I use `break` to terminate the loop.

```
int i = 0;
while(true){
  System.out.println(i++);
  if (i == 10) break;
}
```

Comment: can we use simply flag inside the while condition,what does that mean?

Comment: it means that the the while loop repeats until the flag is false.